How to find my old IP addresses?
I was looking on Facebook and it said I had someone log in multiple times through different IP addresses. But my IP changes frequently so I would like to know how to find out any of my old/recent IP addresses.

You can call your ISP but Facebook supports Geolocation and likely indicates where a login was located, if it was near your location, then it’s a safe bet that login attempt was you

Your computer is very unlikely to have any such record. In fact, your computer is unlikely to even "know" about the IP addresses Facebook is telling you about.
This is because the IPs Facebook sees are the IP addresses outside your network, the public IPs, which mostly belong to your ISP unless you pay for a static IP service or are using a VPN with a static assigned IP address, while your computer only knows about its own private IP address, assigned to it by whatever device is responsible for handing out IP addresses inside your network.
While you could, in theory, create a utility that queries an online service to get your current public IP at regular intervals, and log these, that doesn't tell you what your IP addresses were in the past.
Another option is to ask your ISP, but it is very unlikely they'll have this information, or be willing to give it to you.
In general, when reviewing these sign-in logs, you'll also see a general location the IP records are associated with, and if they show a location you are or have been, you're fine. Good account security is a better way to keep your account secure, including a unique and long password, and using whatever MFA or extra security steps options Facebook offers.

Your best bet is to implement a system that records your ip address every 5 minutes, or whatever interval, and logs the IP as well as the time to either a simple csv file,spreadsheet or database.
You should not need to keep the data more than a week so the file should not get that large.
